Entropy generation in an expanding universe?
If entropy being generated in a system is given by

$$
S = \frac{dQ}{T} = \int \left( \frac{dQ}{dt} \cdot \frac{1}{T} \right) dt
$$

One could have the limit $S = \infty$ if $T \to 0$, so as the universe keeps expanding (assuming it had no cosmological constant) the temperature would asymptote to $0$, meaning that entropy could be endlessly generated?
I think this is wrong because if the universe keeps expanding it would reach heat death, which means that no more entropy could be generated, but this is in contractiction with the formula.
Is it because the formula cannot be applied in such a system?

.
Heat is energy being transferred. dQ goes to zero with T going to zero. You are trying to integrate a function that becomes 0/0 as it goes to infinity. There may very well be a finite amount if the cosmological constant is zero. For others it may be infinity, I don't know.
.
